# Getting Exception: The specified network name is no longer available. (0x80070040) when trying to read HttpRequest Body using ReadToEndAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an API post web method that tries to get the request body out using StreamReader `ReadToEndAsync()`. The majority of the time it works fine, however for very random request I am getting the following exception:

> The client has disconnected.

with inner exception

> The specified network name is no longer available. (0x80070040).

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Logger/Log")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Log()
{
    try
    {
        HttpHelper httpHelper = new HttpHelper();
        var requestBody = await httpHelper.GetRequestBody(Request);
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogException(ex);
        return StatusCode(500);
    }
}

public async Task<string> GetRequestBody(HttpRequest request)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
    {
        return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

Full Exception

```
[Parameters]: {}
[Exception Message]: The client has disconnected
[StackTrace]:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IO.AsyncIOOperation.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.ReadBody()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.ReadAsync(CancellationToken token)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.ReadAsync(Memory`1 memory, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBufferAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEndAsyncInternal()
   at OnlineBookingSystem.Utilities.HttpHelper.GetRequestBody(HttpRequest request) 
   at OnlineBookingSystem.Controllers.LoggingController.Log() 
[Inner Exception]: The specified network name is no longer available. (0x80070040)
[Inner StackTrace]:
```

What is the cause for this? Is the way that I am reading the request body not correct? How can I resolve this?

Comment: I ran the same locally in .netcore 3.1, it worked fine all times. Can you share in which scenario it fails?

Comment: You may take a look at this [link](https://www.minitool.com/news/the-specified-network-name-is-no-longer-available.html).

Comment: @AjeetKumar thanks for the reply. That's the issue, I don't know under what scenario where it actually fails. But it definitely fails because it is logging out the exception. The application is currently published via IIS, and the majority of the time it works fine but randomly it would throw that exception.

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm experiencing the same issue in .Net 7

Answer (score 1):

This would appear to be a bug in asp.net core that is fixed in v5:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/25146

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25437

> Reading the request body may throw an exception. This change adds some extra guards
> for this and presents this as a 4xx response rather than a 5xx response.