# The client has disconnected; The specified network name is no longer available. (0x80070040)

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-6.0

I have noticed in the log file the following exception `The client has disconnected`. The possibility is very rare- ~3 times in a week so its hard to reproduce. Application runs on IIS windows server 2019.

The middleware witch handles exception:

```
    public class RequestHandlingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public RequestHandlingMiddleware
            (RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IWallesterLogger logger)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(httpContext); //<- This line throws an exception


                var rawRequestBody = await (new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync());
               
                await logger.Log(WallesterLogSection.RequestInfoLog, httpContext.Request.Path.Value,
                     new
                     {
                         httpContext.Request.Path.Value,
                         httpContext.Request.Method,
                         rawRequestBody,
                         httpContext.Request.Headers
                     }
                    );
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex, logger);
                throw;
            }
        }
        private async Task HandleExceptionAsync
                                (HttpContext context, Exception exception, IWallesterLogger logger)
        {
            await logger.Log(exception, WallesterLogSection.Exception);
        }

    }

    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.
    public static class LoggerkMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseLoggerMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {

            return builder.UseMiddleware<RequestHandlingMiddleware>();
        }
    }
```

`Program.cs`:

```
// Add services to the container.
var mocking = builder.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("Mocking");
var MockingDb = builder.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("MockingDb");
if (MockingDb)
{
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(x => x.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "ApplicationDb"));
}
else
{
    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
}


builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .WriteTo.File($"logs/{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss")}-logs.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .CreateLogger();

builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseLoggerMiddleware(); // <- add middleware logger
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

And the controller action it tried to reach looks like this:

```
[HttpPost("event")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostEvent(
            [FromBody] object obj)
```

Full exception callstack:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException: The client has disconnected
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070040): The specified network name is no longer available. (0x80070040)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IO.AsyncIOOperation.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.ReadBody()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.ReadAsync(CancellationToken token)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.ReadAsync(Memory`1 memory, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromStreamAsync(Stream utf8Json, ReadBufferState bufferState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadAllAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value, Object container)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at WebApp.Middleware.RequestHandlingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IWallesterLogger logger) in C:\Projects\Pasts\PNS\Wallester\WebApp\Middleware\RequestHandlingMiddleware.cs:line 19
   at WebApp.Middleware.RequestHandlingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IWallesterLogger logger) in C:\Projects\Pasts\PNS\Wallester\WebApp\Middleware\RequestHandlingMiddleware.cs:line 44
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

From the callstack line:19 is code in the middleware `await _next(httpContext);` and line:44 is `throw` command in the catch block.

My question would be what could cause this error, and is there anything we could change to fix it?

Comment: same error you can use as reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64454469/getting-exception-the-specified-network-name-is-no-longer-available-0x8007004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64454469/getting-exception-the-specified-network-name-is-no-longer-available-0x8007004).